# Fastest way to draw a grid

Tags: html

I need to draw a (possibly large) grid of squares. I wonder what sort of layout is the fastest to render.

- each square positioned absolutely
- div for each row, filled with floating squares
- an actual table
- some other?

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XeN5k/) for an example. But instead of 2x2 I'll need a grid of, say, 40x40.

Comment: I'd vote for simple `inline-block` DIVs. But you'll have to actually test several possibilities in several browsers if you're concerned with performance. (Tables must be really fast but they're almost impossible to keep under control for non-tabular usages.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, why would tables be fast? I was under the impression that they use somewhat more complex layout algorithms. Also, how would I banchmark this accurately? Are there "started drawing", "finished drawing" events?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there will be much difference in rendering time - they all use a similar amount of code.

The absolute positioning is likely to create the most css, so I'd personally avoid that one.

Is it for showing tabular data or just decoration?  If the former, use a table.
If the latter, could you achieve it with a tiled graphic as the background of a single cell instead?

Also: A javascript loop to create them is likely to keep your code tidier than writing each square manually.

Comment: It will be a decoration, generated by JS. Is the amount of code an important factor in rendering time? I've seen browsers slow down with just a few hundred items - that shouldn't take any time to read.

Comment: A tiling background image is probably the best bet if it is decoration only - keeps the decoration in the style sheet and your html content-only.  Regarding rendering : in modern browsers, I've only ever found it to be slowed down by heavy things like video and badly-written javascript (usually ajax).  I personally don't see it as something you should worry about in this case as the code is quite simple.